# Telegram Bot Api: как получить кол-во пользователей зашедших в канал по ссылке

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Я создаю ботом несколько инвайт ссылок в приватный канал в телеграмме через бот апи. Вопрос, как подсчитать кол-во пользователей зашедших по определенной ссылке используя бот апи. Бот - администратор канала, со всеми правами. При вступлении пользователей в канал - ничего не присылается в вебхук бота.

Ответ должен использовать Telegram Bot API, но если вы напишете полный пример кода то можно и Telegram API(я не понимаю как с ним работать) - если он применим в данной ситуации.

Вот так создаются ссылки:

```
$params = [
    'chat_id' => '-100*********'
];

$ch = curl_init($TgAPI.'bot'.'token'.'/createChatInviteLink');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT    => 60
));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

print $output;
```

Вот так пытаюсь получить кол-во пользователей:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Load telegram-bot/api

$apiToken = 'hash';
$inviteLink = 'link';
$chatId     = '-100*****';

$telegram = new \TelegramBot\Api\Client($apiToken);

$importers = $telegram->messages->getChatInviteImporters($chatId, $inviteLink);

print_r($importers);
```

Возникает ошибка:
Fri Jul 14 07:33:40.260995 2023] [php7:error] [pid 698972] [client 127.0.0.1:45142] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getChatInviteImporters() on null in /home/leonid/Web/telegram/testMethod.php:36\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /home/leonid/Web/telegram/testMethod.php on line 36

**Update: Я написал ответ, использующий "Telegram Bot Api", но всё еще хочу знать как использовать "Telegram Api", а именно метод getChatInviteImporters.**

Comment: есть же апдейты/хуки такие https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmemberupdated Для отправки хуки условия [указаны](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmemberupdated)

Comment: @teran Не приходят такие апдейты, в вопросе написано - ничего не приходит при вступлении в канал и выходе. Другие хуки, например пост, приходят. Права у бота включены все.

Comment: а на какие хуки вы подписываете бота?

Comment: Все, разобрался. Проблема была в вебхуке. Установил allowed_updates во все возможные значения, не хватало chat_member

Answer (score 0):

В вебхук не приходили данные о вступлении/покидания канала. По умолчанию установка веб хука создается без правила chat_member.
Я это исправил и появилась возможность считать пользователей зашедших по определенной инвайт ссылке. Инвайт ссылка содержится в данных присылаемых в вебхук, но ссылка должна быть создана ботом. Если ссылка создана другим администратором(ботом админом например) то инвайт ссылка приходит обрезанная, просто в конце ссылки вместо ключа подставляется "..."

Вот пример кода - устанавливающий все подписки вебхука:

```php
function setWebhook($token) {
  global $TgAPI,$HOST;
  
  $url = $HOST."webhook.php?token=".$token;
  
  $POST = [
      'url'             => $url,
      'max_connections' => 10,
      'allowed_updates' => json_encode(['message','edited_message','channel_post','edited_channel_post','inline_query','chosen_inline_result','callback_query','shipping_query','pre_checkout_query','poll','poll_answer','my_chat_member','chat_member','chat_join_request'])
  ];
  
  $ch = curl_init($TgAPI.'bot'.$token.'/setWebhook');
  curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
      CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
      CURLOPT_POST => 1,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $POST,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT    => 60
  ));
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close($ch);

  return [
    'code'   => $httpcode,
    'output' => json_decode($output,true)
  ];
  
}
```

Пример того что приходит в вебхук при вступлении в канал, chat_member обьект:

```json
{
  "update_id": 1234567890,
  "chat_member": {
    "chat": {
      "id": -1001234567890,
      "title": "Test",
      "type": "channel"
    },
    "from": {
      "id": 1234567890,
      "is_bot": false,
      "first_name": "Test",
      "last_name": "Test"
    },
    "date": 1689332573,
    "old_chat_member": {
      "user": {
        "id": 1234567890,
        "is_bot": false,
        "first_name": "Test",
        "last_name": "Test"
      },
      "status": "left"
    },
    "new_chat_member": {
      "user": {
        "id": 1234567890,
        "is_bot": false,
        "first_name": "Test",
        "last_name": "Test"
      },
      "status": "member"
    },
    "invite_link": {
      "invite_link": "https://t.me/+hash",
      "creator": {
        "id": 1234567890,
        "is_bot": true,
        "first_name": "TestBot",
        "username": "TestBot"
      },
      "creates_join_request": false,
      "is_primary": true,
      "is_revoked": false
    }
  }
}
```